# using(adding) images to html with help image_pack_tag by Webpacker in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpack-4, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a problem with adding image to web-page
I try to use Webpack
so I download images in application.js

```
const images = require.context('./assets/images/', true)
const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)
```

after that i try to implement their in html.erb

```
          <div class="modal-body"
          <%= image_pack_tag 'calibration.png' %>
          </div>
```

so, i have this error
what i do wrong? and what i need to do?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is solved.
My mistake was that I specified the wrong path; a correct variant is:

```
const images = require.context('../../assets/images', true)
```

After that, place the image in
`public/packs/media/images/`
so you can implement it in HTML in two ways:

1. `<%= image_pack_tag 'media/images/name_of_image.png' %>`
2. `<img src="<%= asset_pack_path 'media/images/name_of_image.png' %>" width="100%" height="100%" alt=" demo instructions"></img>`